# Using Fqcebook Stream Table to query friends news feed

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Hi trying to use the stream table to access a friends news feed

```
"SELECT post_id, created_time, message, comments, source_id, actor_id, target_id, type 
   FROM stream 
  WHERE filter_key IN (SELECT filter_key 
             FROM stream_filter 
            WHERE uid=".$friendID.") 
             AND is_hidden = 0"
```

But I keep getting an error stating `can only use stream for the current user that is logged in`. Is it possible to query the stream table to query for friends news feeed or is there another fql method to do this.

many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's impossible to query another user's feed using fql, however, you can query a friends feed by using the graph api, the entry point is /feed.